# Spring MVC Printing for webapplication

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, printing

Can any one please suggest me some useful links to take print in web application using Spring.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition, link to print current page can be written the following way:

```
<a href="javascript: if(window.print) window.print()">Print</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

i recommand you to look at CSS to customize the look and feel of your printed pages.

see http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/05/how-to-create-a-simple-print-css-for-your-site/